# ROC_AUC is better then ballanced accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm testing different algorithms like: logistic regression, SVM's.... with a 10 fold nested Cross-validation. I'm using scikit-learn with gridsearchCV.

But it is a little bit strange, that nearly every roc_AUC is better then the ballanced accuracy. Maybe I did something wrong? 
There are  73% of 1 values and 27% of 0 values.

The ROC_AUC is computed with:

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(expected, predicted1)
fpr1, tpr1, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(expi, predi, pos_label=1.0)
spec=1-fpr1[1]
sens=tpr1[1]
auc=metrics.auc(fpr,tpr)
ballanced_accuracy=(sens+spec)/2
```

I'm using 2 kinds of roc_curces, du to im getting with the fpr and tpr an array about y predictions e.g. fpr has for example 230 values, same with tpr.

For fpr1 and tpr1I have 1 value, with them i'll calculate the specificity and sensitivity.

The expected and expi vector, have the same values.
Predicted1, have the y-predict_proba scores and predi has just the classification, based on the predict_proba function ( 1 or 0 )

Random Forest:

- ballanced accuracy: 0.76 +/- 0.07
- roc_auc:            0.83 +/- 0.05

SVM:

- ballanced accuracy: 0.77 +/- 0.06
- roc_auc:            0.83 +/- 0.06

Decision Tree Classifier:

- ballanced accuracy: 0.69 +/- 0.05
- roc_auc:            0.69 +/- 0.05

AdaBoost-Decision Tree Classifier:

- ballanced accuracy: 0.75 +/- 0.06
- roc_auc:            0.80 +/- 0.06

Comment: it is unclear what the actual question is. it needs more focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AUC is the area under the ROC curve and gives information about the behavior of a model as one moves the threshold, so while generally speaking higher AUC values mean you *can find* a threshold that has good accuracy,

1. your actual model accuracy does depend on the chosen threshold, and
2. AUC and accuracy are different concepts and there is absolutely no reason for it to be wrong that one is bigger than the other.